# Timeout expired exception in c#.net and sql server project

Tags: c#, sql, timeout

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
>   operation or the server is not responding.

I am getting this error in my project. Project is working fine for more than 2 years without this error. Now i am getting this error *frequently*.

What could be the reason for this? I have closed each and every opened connection. Is there any setting in SQL Server 2005 to avoid this issue? Or this problem is caused by network availability?

Comment: Deadlocks? Uncommited transactions?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the timeout?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is impossible to help you without seeing your work..

Comment: May be your procedure taking long time to execute

Comment: But i have never faces this issue in last 2 years. It started 2 months back and have the face the issue for 2-3 times not frequently.

Comment: there are no deadlocks. haven't used timeout. Increasing size of database can cause this issue????

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to network availability, but I had this problem some month ago. 
In my case TCP/TP and share memory setting had changed in SQL Server Configuration Management.
Please check your SQL Server Configuration Management settings.

Answer (score 0):

Today i have faced the same issue. So i collected all the logs.

In sql logs i got this error   :

"Autogrow of file 'SSPB_log' in database 'SSPB' was cancelled by user or timed out after 30124 milliseconds.  Use ALTER DATABASE to set a smaller FILEGROWTH value for this file or to explicitly set a new file size."

In my application logs I got this:

"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

Does this errors related to each other??